# Use regex to parse characters on a line of text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple lines of text in a file, and I want to parse out two separate lines.  I want to get lines like this:

```
# x_be
# x_ls
# l_rs
```

So, it would be '#' to the end of that one line.  Also, I want to get lines like this:

So, in this case, it would be '- id:' until the end of that one line.  How can I do that?  I thought the code would like like the sample below, but that doesn't match  anything at all.

```
with open('C:\\path_here\\final_result.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read()

start = '^#'
end = '\n'

import re
results = re.findall(r'start\s+(.*?)\end',lines,flags=re.DOTALL)

prep_results = list(map(lambda x: x.split("\n"), results))

output = [start+','.join(i)+end for i in prep_results]

with open('C:\\path_here\\parsed.txt','w') as f:
    for line in output:
        f.write("%s\n" % line)
```

I'm trying to pick a start and end point, so I can make this dynamic, and pick out multiple lines in some instances.  Most of the time though, the start and end variables that I'm searching for are on the same line of text.

Comment: Can you show some part the input file?

Comment: Input text please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

exclude = [" source"]
ex_reg = "(?!{})".format('|'.join(exclude))
start = ["#",'- id:']
start[1] += ex_reg 
end = "\n"
reg = re.compile('\s*({})'.format('|'.join(start)),flags=re.S)

for i in data.split(end):
    if re.match(reg,i):
        print(i.strip())
```

Looks like overkill but you can add as many exclude words as you'd like. But when you add them, mind the spaces before them.

Comment: Thanks Omkar, that works perfect for the lines that start with '#'.  For the lines that start with '- id:', I just noticed that there are a bunch of '- id: source' coming through, and I don't want these.  Start with '- id:' but don't include '- id: source'?  Thanks.